# Locate index of rows in a dataframe that have the value of NA

Tags: r, dataframe, na

Suppose that we have the following data frame:

```
>  dataset1
      x
  1   1
  2   2
  3   3
  4   NA
  5   5
```

I want to come up with a R command that computes the row index of the 1-column data frame that contains the value of 'NA'. More specifically, in above dataset1 example, such command would return 4 - because the 'NA' appears in the 4th row of the data frame. How can I make this happen? thank you!

Comment: see `?which`, `?is.na` ...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

As suggested by Ben Bolker, you can use both `which` and `is.na` as in:

```
> which(is.na(dataset1), arr.ind=TRUE)
  row col
4   4   1  # NA is in row 4 and column 1
```

Comment: or `which(is.na(dataset1[[1]]))`, since the OP said they wanted the answer "4"

Answer (score 6):

An alternative approach using functions from the `tidyverse` ecosystem:

```
> dataset1 %>%
     rowid_to_column() %>%
     filter(is.na(x))
  rowid  x
1     4 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

create `newdataset1` which is a table formed after deleting rows with missing column values from `dataset1`
use `-which(is.na)`

```
   newdataset1<-dataset1[-which(is.na(dataset1$x)),]
```

Answer (score 1):

This code returns dataframe which contains only rows with an empty values in your_dataframe
`your_dataframe[unique(which(is.na(your_dataframe), arr.ind=TRUE)[,1]),]`

or using dplyr

`your_dataframe %>%
dplyr::setdiff(., na.omit(.))`